# Django ORM query to find all objects which don't have a recent related object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a repeating pattern in my code where a model has a related model (one-to-many) which tracks its history/status.  This related model can have many objects representing a point-in-time snapshot of the model's state.

For example:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    pass

class Subscription(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    data_point = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime)

#Example objects
p = Provile()
subscription1 = Subscription(profile=p, data_point=32, created=datetime.datetime(2011, 7 1)
subscription2 = Subscription(profile=p, data_point=2, created=datetime.datetime(2011, 8 1)
subscription3 = Subscription(profile=p, data_point=3, created=datetime.datetime(2011, 9 1)
subscription4 = Subscription(profile=p, data_point=302, created=datetime.datetime(2011, 10 1)
```

I often need to query these models to find all of the "Profile" objects that haven't had a subscription update in the last 3 days or similar.  I've been using subselect queries to accomplish this:

```
q = Subscription.objects.filter(created__gt=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=3).values('id').query
Profile.objects.exclude(subscription__id__in=q).distinct()
```

The problem is that this is terribly slow when large tables are involved.  Is there a more efficient pattern for a query such as this?  Maybe some way to make Django use a JOIN instead of a SUBSELECT (seems like getting rid of all those inner nested loops would help)?

I'd lilke to use the ORM, but if needed I'd be willing to use the .extra() method or even raw SQL if the performance boost is compelling enough.

I'm running against Django 1.4alpha (SVN Trunk) and Postgres 9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Max
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Profile.objects.annotate(last_update=Max('subscription__created')).filter(last_update__lt=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=3))
```

Aggregation (and annotation) is awesome-sauce, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: I ran a test query and it is very slow (still running an hour later).  I have an index on the created field.  The table is fairly large though (50 million rows or so).

Comment: That's the point where you need to start looking into database optimization. Devoting more RAM to the instance, moving the database to its own instance, if it's not already segregated, or even setting up a cluster, but what I just gave you is the most efficient you're going to get as far as optimizing the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add a DB index to `created`:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime, db_index=True)
```

As a rule of thumb, any column that is used in queries for lookup or sorting should be indexed, unless you are heavy on writing operations (in that case you should think about using a separate search index, maybe).

Queries using db columns without indexes are only so fast. If you want to analyze the query bottlenecks in more detail, turn on logging for longer running statements (e.g. 200ms and above), and do an `explain analyze` (postgres) on the long running queries.

EDIT:
I've only now seen in your comment that you have an index on the field. In that case, all the more reason to look at the output of `explain analyze`.

1. to make sure that the index is really used, and to its full extend.
2. to look whether postgres is unnecessarily writing to disk instead of using memory

See
- on query planning http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html

Maybe this helps as an intro: http://blog.it-agenten.com/2015/11/tuning-django-orm-part-2-many-to-many-queries/